# Change scoring algorithm in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, scoring

Is it possible to define custom scoring in ElasticSearch? 
for example tell the ES to compute count of similar words as score.

Is it possible?

Comment: hi, have you found something useful with fielddata disabled?

Answer (score 0):

Im answering first part of your question . Yes, you can have a custom similarity module in elasticsearch. Please refer to [documentation here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-modules-similarity.html)